# NameError: Outside Variable not defined

Tags: python, function

What is the correct way to call `Score()` inside of `Possible_Outcomes()`?

I keep getting the following error:

```
A_win = A_score+(K*(1-win_probability_A))
NameError: name 'A_score' is not defined
```

I spent some time going through the suggested answers but could not implement a solution successfully. To be more specific, I can't understand how to use multiple return values from one function inside of another function. Thank you.

```
def Score():
    A_score= 1500
    B_score= 1600
    win_probability_A= 1/(1+10**((B_score-A_score)/400))
    win_probability_B= 1/(1+10**((A_score-B_score)/400))
    return A_score, B_score, win_probability_A, win_probability_B

y=Score()

def Possible_Outcomes(y):
    K=int(32)
    A_win = A_score+(K*(1-win_probability_A))
    A_loss = A_score+(K*(0-win_probability_A))
    B_loss = B_score+(K*(0-win_probability_B))
    B_win= B_score+(K*(1-win_probability_B))
    return 

Possible_Outcomes(y)
```

Comment: *win\_probability\_A* (or its equivalent from inside *Possible\_Outcomes*) is `y[2]` (as returned by *Score*). *BTW*: naming is truly awful.

Comment: What is `K=int(32)` doing?

Comment: Thanks Cristi. Possible_Outcomes(y[2]) gives me a Syntax Error so I misunderstood your comment. How can we use all variables defined in Score() within Possible_Outcomes()?

Comment: Hey Austin, the K factor is just the maximum number of points can be exchanged during a match.

Answer (score 3):

What you have is an issue of scope. You do define `A_score`, but only in the context of your function `Score()`. Outside of that scope, Python doesn't know where to look for `A_score`, or any of the other variables you defined there.

I've rewritten your code somewhat, with what I believe is what you intended to do:

```
def Score():
    A_score = 1500
    B_score = 1600
    win_probability_A = 1/(1+10**((B_score-A_score)/400))
    win_probability_B = 1/(1+10**((A_score-B_score)/400))
    return A_score, B_score, win_probability_A, win_probability_B

y = Score()

def Possible_Outcomes(values):
    A_score, B_score, win_probability_A, win_probability_B = values
    K = int(32)
    A_win = A_score+(K*(1-win_probability_A))
    A_loss = A_score+(K*(0-win_probability_A))
    B_loss = B_score+(K*(0-win_probability_B))
    B_win= B_score+(K*(1-win_probability_B))
    return A_win, A_loss, B_loss, B_win

Possible_Outcomes(y)
```

Comment: Thank you, it did work. I guess the takeaway here is that anytime you use non-local variables inside a function you must declare them at the beginning of that function. Does that mean the return statement inside Score() is unnecessary?

Comment: That's not quite the takeaway here. We didn't actually need to define `A_score` inside of your `Possible_Outcomes()` function, I did that to be consistent with your code. Inside of `Possibe_Outcomes()`, you could have replaced all instances of `A_score` with `values[0]`, for example. The takeaway here should be that just because a variable is defined somewhere in your code, doesn't mean it exists everywhere. Just be more careful about scope.

Comment: I understand that variables are local but it was my understanding that if a function defines a variable and then that function is called inside another function than all variables inside the first function will be carried over to the second.

Answer (score 2):

You can add one line to get the values returned by `scope()` function

```
A_score, B_score, win_probability_A, win_probability_B=y
```

Also, you can call the function inside the second function to improve the readability

```
def Possible_Outcomes():
    K=int(32) # not sure what you are trying to do here can be just K=32
    A_score, B_score, win_probability_A, win_probability_B = Score() # fetch all the values returned by the function 
    A_win = A_score+(K*(1-win_probability_A))
    A_loss = A_score+(K*(0-win_probability_A))
    B_loss = B_score+(K*(0-win_probability_B))
    B_win= B_score+(K*(1-win_probability_B))
    #return # you do not need to return in every function

Possible_Outcomes()
```

Other approach may include use of global variables which I would not recommend unless left with the only option

Comment: Thank you. I'm just trying to understand how functions receive variables from other functions, especially when there is more than one variable to receive. So the idea here is that you declare the Score() variables inside of Possible_Outcomes() before using them correct?

Comment: When you return more than one object it is returned as an iterable like a tuple.You can try debugging by printing the elements `print(Score())` it will return the tuple which has a value tied up with a fixed index which you can access like `[0]` which will give the value of `A_score` now we can unpack the iterable and can store in the way we want. so `A_score` is the value present at the first iterable and so on. That is just the pythonic way to do it. Try googling unpacking in python

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation